# A command to merge video and audio file using "ffmpeg" and remove the source files

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to merge audio and video using ffmpeg. I use following command but it keeps the input (source) files while I want to delete them after they were merged. I want to see if there is a command for that or not!

`ffmpeg -i "a.avi" -i "a.wav" -y -acodec copy -vcodec copy "b.avi"`

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with ffmpeg. Issue another command compatible with your shell to delete the files (```rm``` on linux or ```del``` on windows)

Comment: `ffmpeg` has no such option, so you will have to move or delete the files with other tools, such as mentioned by Ely.

Answer (score -1):

The same command adding `&& rm a.avi a.wav` at the end.